# How to invoke an onStop for espresso UI testing

Tags: android, android-espresso, coded-ui-tests

I am testing my UI, and need to test a case that results in the UI changing once onStop() has been called. Does anyone know a good way to mock an onStop()?

Answer (score 0):

Override onStop with public access specifier and call `activityRule.getActivity().onStop()` for your `activityRule`.